# Prevent from asking user credentials on REST call

Tags: javascript, rest, 2016

When a javascript call to REST api from site page is executed, if user has no permissions on the site, he will be asked for credentials multiple times in a browser. How can I avoid/prevent that? Code below:

```
function requestRestApi(endpoint, options) {
  var opts = {
    type: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    headers: { ACCEPT: "application/json;odata=verbose" }
  };
  return jQuery.ajax(jQuery.extend(opts, options));
} 


requestRestApi(siteUrl + "/_api/web/currentuser?$select=LoginName")
.then(function (data) {
  var user = data.d;
  var endpoint = siteUrl + "_api/web/getList('" 
    + listServerRelatedUrl + "')/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='"
    + encodeURIComponent(user.LoginName) + "'";

  requestRestApi(endpoint)
  .then(function(data) {
     var userPerms = data.d.GetUserEffectivePermissions;
     var perms = new SP.BasePermissions();
     var SP_PERMISSIONKIND_OPEN = 17;
     perms.initPropertiesFromJson(userPerms);
     console.info("Can open=" + perms.has(SP_PERMISSIONKIND_OPEN));
   });
});
```

Comment: Is this related to the **Auth** Type somehow? Am I misconfigured my REST request or my farm's auth?

Comment: I have faced the same behavior with RequestExecutor approach as well, as with JSOM too.

Answer (score 2):

One potential fix could be to send an `OPTIONS` request before the `GET`. `OPTIONS` may be failing on 401 responses [tbc].
It it does, you simply need to check the response from the `OPTIONS`, and don't try to issue the `GET` if it failed with 401.

Comment: Before I read you answer, was thinking about the same. Today I had tried to execute `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` but with no luck

Comment: If you vote up this answer, please explain if it works for you, and in which version of SharePoint (mine on-perm 2016 is not)

Comment: @dbardakov What was the outcome of this for you, I have the same issue.

Comment: @Batman In case of NTLM auth there is no way browser won't ask you to enter new creds in response to 401. In case it was a call to another site collection to which user doen't have ANY perms at all.

Comment: Options are 1. Switch to SSO auth provider (ADFS/Forms/...) 2. Make sure users are at least in site visitor group and then use `doesuserhaspermission`'s endpoints.

Comment: In our case (custom home page navigation with links to current site collection and other site collections as well) we created list to store navigation item (uri) with custom perms (much the same as on resource) on each item.

Comment: I ended up changing from querying the site directly to using Search API instead. So I leave the permission handling to search and I don't get credential prompts.